# ActionFilter to check for ModelState.IsValid is never hit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I wrote an ActionFilter to check if my modelstate is valid (so I can log the issue):

```
public class ValidationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    { ... }
}
```

My breakpoint is never hit, I do get an output in Postman:

> {
>       "errors": {
>           "RequiredText": [
>               "Test - RequiredText is required"
>           ]
>       },
>       "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
>       "status": 400,
>       "traceId": "0HLOBA7E4R7SL:00000002"
>   }

I'm asuming that .NET Core does the validation beforehand.
Is there a way to turn this off so I my Attribute is used?

Comment: One of the ways to turn off default validation would be to remove validation attributes from your model. Then, validate on your own in your filter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you must disable the default behavior by setting `SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter` option to true. You can set this option to true in the ConfigureServices method. Like,

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
    });
}
```